# Angular CLI not enforcing defaulting .onpush changedetection with newly created components

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my angular 10.2.4 project, we are using `@schematics/angular@10.2.4` and want all newly created components to have .onpush changedetection as default. So that when a developer creates a new component using the CLI, for example `ng g c my-component`, the resulting component already has the .onpush changedetection hooks in place when its created.

To do this, I have run this command:
`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.changeDetection OnPush`

And that has placed the following inside my angular.json file:

```
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss",
          "changeDetection": "OnPush"
        }
      }
```

However, still when we create new components using the CLI, for example `ng g c my-component`, they do not have any changedetection at all specified. Is this not possible with this version of the CLI? `"@angular/cli": "^10.2.4",`

Answer (score 0):

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.changeDetection OnPush`

changed the dot between `angular` and `component` for a `:`

Also notice how you have a schematic already for your components `@schematics/angular:component` and you created a new one just below with a different structure. Just add the `changeDetection` change to your first shematic

Comment: Thanks for catching the dot vs colon. However, the same result. We are only using the CLI to test creating new components, we are using `ng g c my-component` for example. This project is an angular 10.2.4 CLI project so perhaps that is not supported?